# Repeating order based on user input

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core-2.1

Scenario:
I have a form for creating orders, which are stored in a SQL-db in Azure. In the form, there is an option for recurring order, where the user can choose between different options (like which days, how many times per day and so on) for when an order will be performed. So most of the repeating orders will have different repeat-patterns.

Right now there is a "home made" internal function that polls the orders in the database to determine if the order is going to be created or not based on the repeating-pattern.

But Im wondering if there is a way to have this functionality externally and use Services provided by Azure i.e like Azure Function which also offers monitoring and if it´s possible to do this by infrastructure as code not via Azure portal. Yes, one option is to actually port the "home made" function into an Azure Function. But would be awesome to automate this process, instead of just polling the database.

I have seen examples of using HangFire and Quartz.NET, but I prefer doing this with Azure Services.

Comment: Probably not exactly as you're asking, in that Azure Functions can have a variety of triggers, including timers, but it would become very complex having multiple timer-functions for each order.
The best I suspect you'd do is having an Azure Function trigger every (say...) 15 minutes and check which orders need to be processed, much in the same way you're doing now.
That said, this is a great use for a Function - something lightweight that sits in the background and posts orders to be processed by some other application.

Comment: @ScottLeckie Thanks for the reply! Yes, I considered to use one Function for the polling, and call another Function for other triggers. But as you mentioned, in the end it will become to complex for the task I guess.